# Git commits in emacs without changing window layout?

Tags: git, emacs

I normally work in emacs with the frame split into two side-by-side windows. Committing a change via git (`C-x v v`) opens a buffer in the other window for the change comment. The problem is that when I finish the comment and type `C-c C-c`, the window containing the comment is killed along with the VC-log buffer. Then I have to split the frame into two windows again and find the buffer that had been in deleted window.

Is there any way to keep this process (`C-x v v` [commit message] `C-c C-c`) from messing up my window layout? I'd be happy for the VC-log to open in the other window and then disappear without changing the window layout, or for the VC-log to temporarily split one of the windows, as long as my original buffer/window layout is restored when I'm done with the commit. I could write a wrapper function for `vc-next-action` that saves and restores the window configuration, but it seems like there should be a more straightforward way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick look through the vc options offered no possibility, but you can advise `vc-next-action` (bound to `C-x v v`) with a `save-window-excursion` that restores the windows

```
(defadvice vc-next-action (around keep-windows activate)
  (save-window-excursion
    ad-do-it))
```

There is also `winner-mode` for general restoring. And if you use git, you definitely should look at magit.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do exactly what I want (the VC-log buffer gets created out-of-sight, and when I select it and finish with `C-c C-c` the same issue occurs), but I think it's close. I didn't know about defadvice, so thanks! I'll play around with this and see if I can get it to do what I want.

Comment: `winner-mode` is really great. The previous window configuration is just a `C-c <left>` away (and repeat to continue back through the window config history). Having that ability at hand for *any* situation in which the windows change on you unexpectedly is brilliant, and it means you can do things like temporarily maximise a window, and then simply go back to how it was before.

Comment: I just glanced at it, but winner-mode looks like something I really need! I'm about to leave the office now, but I'll check it later tonight. Thanks Michael and phils!

Comment: Okay, winner-mode is the solution, not just for this, but for any time I want to restore my window configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with the same problem. This seem to work.

```
(defadvice log-edit-done (around keep-windows activate)
  (save-window-excursion
    ad-do-it))
```

help for C-c C-c in vc-log buffer shows this:

C-c C-c runs the command log-edit-done, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in `log-edit.el'.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll give this a try. Fortunately, this has been fixed in Emacs 24.